# to check empty or null value in a cell of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, cells

I want to check empty of null cell of datagridview . for that I am using following code , but it is flashing message even cells are filled.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5 || e.ColumnIndex == 6)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == DBNull.Value ||
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()))           
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter  value");
        }
    }

}
```

where is mistake ..

thanks in advance ...

Comment: It is customary to show the message. But I see one problem, the cell value would not be `null`, it would be `DbNull.Value`

Comment: What's the value of the cell when you think it should be null? Maybe DbNull.Value?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are checking 2 different things:

`e.ColumnIndex` and `CurrentCell`

Its best to use only 1 of those so `CurrentCell` could be replaced by:

```
dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]
```

So the full code becomes:

```
if ((e.ColumnIndex == 5 || e.ColumnIndex == 6) && e.RowIndex != -1)
{
    var cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

    if (cellValue == null || cellValue == DBNull.Value 
     || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cellValue.ToString()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter  value");
    }
}
```

**Note:** the CellLeave event triggers when you (you guessed it) leave a cell (select another, deselect, whatever). So the `e.ColumnIndex/RowIndex` is different from the `CurrentCell` as you just left it. If you want to check on click, just use the click event handler.

Comment: I used your suggestion ,but getting same response  i.e message even when the cells having value .

Answer (score 1):

The 'CellLeave' event will be fired every time you navigate from a cell, and if you have not entered into a cell, then you will not get an 'leave' event on that cell.

If you want to check a edited cell is not empty then you may want to use the 'CellEndEdit' event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

            if (cell.Value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Value.ToString()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter some velue in cell");
            }
        }
```

Comment: "cell.Value?.ToString()"  ,  is "?" ok or just typing error , I have tried  "cell.Value.ToString()" and geeting "NuLLRefrenceException was unhandled by user code".

Comment: '?' is object null checker in C# 6.0.

Comment: ok, in that case use (cell.Value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Value.ToString())

Comment: I have already done that but getting error "NuLLRefrenceException was unhandled by user code"..

Comment: Sounds like the 'dataGridView1' is null or the row[I] or the column[I] is null. Can you stop at break point on the line 'var cell = ...' and check the objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142261/discussion-between-jegan-and-speedyraz).

Comment: @Jegan Thanks! The `?` solved my null error problem!! I was at the end of my wits trying to figure how to avoid the stupid `NuLLReference` error. I didnt know such a simple thing existed!

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellleave(v=vs.110).aspx)
:

> Occurs when a cell loses input focus and is no longer the current cell.

This mean that `dataGridView1.CurrentCell` is no longer the cell you want.

To get the correct cell use:

```
dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]
```